# Two equivalent definitions of semisimplicity of group representations, proof by Zorn's lemma, a “counterexample” from the Fourier transform theory

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, rt.representation-theory, set-theory, lie-groups, fourier-transform

Consider a representation $A$ of a group $G$ in a complex vector space ${\mathbb{V}}$:
$$
 A:~~G~\longrightarrow~\operatorname{GL}({\mathbb{V}})~~,
 $$
and let ${\mathbb{V}}$ be decomposable into a finite or infinite direct sum
$$
 {\mathbb{V}}~=~\bigoplus_i {\mathbb{V}}_i
 $$
of invariant subspaces carrying irreducibles $A_i$ :
$$
A(G)~{\mathbb{V}}_i\subseteq{\mathbb{V}}_i~~,\qquad A(G)~=~
\bigoplus_i A_i(G)~~.
 $$

Complete (algebraic) reducibility can be defined in two ways.

DEFINITION 1.

A representation $A$ is completely reducible if it splits into a (finite or infinite) direct sum of irreducibles.

DEFINITION 2.

A representation $A$ is completely reducible if any of its subrepresentations has a complementary subrepresentation.

In topology, these definitions are not equivalent, but in algebra they are. A proof of the fact that $~$DEF 1 $~\Longrightarrow~$ DEF 2$~$ can be found at [Two definitions of complete algebraic reducibility are equivalent by Zorn's lemma. Does this equivalence stay for topological spaces?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4340895/two-definitions-of-complete-algebraic-reducibility-are-equivalent-by-zorns-lemm).
Now, the converse statement.

THEOREM: $~~~$DEF 2 $~~\Longrightarrow~$ DEF 1

Based on Zorn's lemma, the proof is simple but a bit lengthy. So I provide it in the end of my post. Now, I go directly to what seems to be a counterexample, a simple fact from the theory of Fourier transform. I wish to know why this “counterexample” fails to fall under the auspices of the above Theorem.

Consider the representation of $\mathbb R$ on $L^2({\mathbb R})$ by translations $
 f(x)~\longmapsto~f(x~+~a)
 $
written as
$$
 {\mathbb{R}} \ni a~:\quad f~\longmapsto~f\circ\hat{\cal{R}}_a~~.
 $$
An ${L^2({\mathbb R})}$ function can be Fourier-expanded as
$$
 f(x)~=\int e^{ 2~\pi~ i~ t~ x}~ F(t)~dt~~.\tag{*}\label{star}
 $$

Since
$
 ~f \in {L^2({\mathbb R})} \Longrightarrow \hat{\cal{R}}_a  f \in {L^2({\mathbb R})}~
 $,
we can expand also the function $f\circ\hat{\cal{R}}_a~ (x) =f(x+a)~$:
$$
 f(x~+~ a)~=~\int e^{2~\pi~ i~ t~ x}~ F_a(t)~dt~~.
 $$
On the other hand, the insertion of $~ x+a~$ instead of $x$ in \eqref{star} renders us
$$
 f(x+a)~=\int e^{ 2~\pi~ i~ t~ x}~ e^{ 2~\pi~ i~ t~ a}~ F(t)~dt~~.
 $$
The former and the latter formulae yield:
$$
 f(x)~\longmapsto~f(x~+~a)\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad F(t)~\longmapsto~e^{2~\pi~ i~ t~ a}~ F(t)~~.\tag{**}\label{starstar}
 $$
This way, the Fourier transform establishes an isomorphism between the translation representation of $\mathbb R$ on $L^2({\mathbb{R}})$ and the representation realised by multiplication by exponentials.

By Schur's lemma, an irreducible, if it exists, must be one-dimensional. This means that there is such a $t$ that \eqref{star} becomes
$$
 f(x)~= e^{~ 2~\pi~ i~ t~ x}~ F(t)~~.
 $$
while \eqref{starstar} becomes
$$
 f(x+a)~= e^{~ 2~\pi~ i~ t~ x}~ e^{~ 2~\pi~ i~ t~ a}~ F(t)~~.
 $$
Combined, these two expressions result in
$$
 f(x+a)~= ~ e^{~ 2~\pi~ i~ t~ a}~f(x)~~.\tag{***}\label{starstarstar}
 $$

Such a function, however, will not be residing in $L^2({\mathbb{R }})$.
Indeed, equality (***) enables us to write the squared norm $~\lVert~f~\rVert^2~=~\int dx~\lvert f(x)\rvert^2$ as
$$
 \lVert f\rVert^2=\int da~\lvert~e^{~ 2~\pi~ i~ t~ a}~f(0)~\rvert^2~=~\lvert~f(0)~\rvert^2~\int da~\lvert~e^{~ 2~\pi~ i~ t~ a}~\rvert^2~=~\infty~~.
 $$

Thus the representation of $\mathbb R$ in $L^2({\mathbb R})$ does NOT expand into irreducibles. So it is not completely reducible in the sense of DEF 1.

At the same time, it is completely reducible in the sense of DEF 2. This is so, because for any measurable set $S\subset\mathbb R$, the $L^2$ space of functions $f$ for which the Fourier transform $F$ has support in $S$ is an invariant closed subspace. Since the complement of a measurable set is measurable, any topological subrepresentation of the translation representation of $\mathbb R$ on $L^2({\mathbb{R}})$ has a topological complement, and therefore obeys the conditions of DEF 2.
This fact is known in the Fourier community, and was discussed at length at [Complete reducibility, in linear algebra versus topology. The example of the translation representation of $\mathbb R$ in $L^2(\mathbb R)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4273183/complete-reducibility-in-linear-algebra-versus-topology-the-example-of-the-tra).

So, we have a well known Theorem and a well known fact incompatible with it. How come? My guess is that the below-provided algebraic proof of the Theorem breaks when we choose to stay within $L^2({\mathbb R})$. Specifically, the application of Zorn's lemma to prove Lemma 2 in the proof of the Theorem might be a weak point. Not sure…. Can someone help me, please?

---

PROOF OF THE THEOREM
/borrowed from page 14 in the book [A sentimental journey through representation theory: from finite groups to quivers (via algebras)](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Eserganov/math252/Bookrep.pdf) by C. Gruson and V. Serganova]/

We begin with two simple lemmas.

LEMMA 1

If a reducible representation $A$ of a group $G$ in a complex vector space $\mathbb V$ is completely reducible in the sense of DEF 2, any non-zero subrepresentation of $A$ is also completely reducible in the sense of DEF 2.

PROOF

Suppose that a subrepresentation $A_{W}$ of $A$ is acting in an invariant subspace ${\mathbb{W}}\subset{\mathbb{V}}$. Also let ${\mathbb{W}}$ contain an invariant subspace ${\mathbb{U}}~$:
$$
 {\mathbb{U}}\subset{\mathbb{W}}\subset{\mathbb{V}}~~,\quad A(G){\mathbb{U}}\subseteq{\mathbb{U}}~~,\quad A(G){\mathbb{W}}\subseteq{\mathbb{W}}~~.
 $$
By DEF 2, both ${\mathbb{U}}$ and ${\mathbb{W}}$ have complementary subrepresentations:
$$
 {\mathbb{U}}\oplus{\mathbb{U}}^{~\prime}=~{\mathbb{V}}~~,\quad 
 {\mathbb{W}}\oplus{\mathbb{W}}^{\,\prime}~=~{\mathbb{V}}~~.
 $$
Consequently, ${\mathbb{W}}={\mathbb{U}}\oplus P({\mathbb{U}}^{~\prime})~$, where $P$ is a projector on ${\mathbb{W}}$.

QED

LEMMA 2

If a non-zero representation $A(G)$ in a complex vector space $\mathbb V$ is completely reducible in the sense of Definition 2, it contains an irreducible.

PROOF

For a non-zero $A(G)$ defined in a finite-dimensional space $\mathbb V$, this can be proved by simply selecting a non-zero subrepresentation of minimal dimension. In the case of an infinite-dimensional $\mathbb V$, we fix an arbitrary vector $v\neq\vec{ 0}$ and consider all the invariant subspaces of $\mathbb V$ not containing $v$. For an arbitrary set of such subspaces totally ordered by inclusion, their union serves as the upper bound. By Zorn's lemma, $\mathbb V$ contains a maximal proper invariant subspace ${\mathbb{E}}$ not containing $v$. By DEF 2 of complete reducibility, $\mathbb E$ has an invariant complement, which we denote with ${\mathbb{V}}_1~$:
$$
 {\mathbb{V}}~=~{\mathbb{E}} \oplus {\mathbb{V}}_1~~.
 $$
The invariant complement ${\mathbb{V}}_1$ is irreducible. Otherwise, it would contain a proper invariant subspace ${\mathbb{V}}^{~\prime}_1\subset{\mathbb{V}}_1$, and would be expandable, by LEMMA 1, into a direct sum ${\mathbb{V}}_1={\mathbb{V}}^{~\prime}_1 \oplus {\mathbb{V}}^{~\prime\prime}_1$ of proper nonzero invariant subspaces. This would imply that either $v\notin {\mathbb{E}}\oplus{\mathbb{V}}^{~\prime}_1$ or $v\notin {\mathbb{E}}\oplus{\mathbb{V}}^{~\prime\prime}_1~$, ~which would contradict ${\mathbb E}$ being a maximal invariant subspace not containing $v$.

QED

Now we are prepared to demonstrate that DEF 2 entails DEF 1.

First we observe that, by Lemma 2, the union  $ \bigcup_{i\in\cal I} {\mathbb{V}}_i $   of all irreducibles  ${{\mathbb V}}_i \subset {\mathbb V}$

is non-zero and coincides with $\mathbb V~$:
$$
 \bigcup_{i\in\cal I}{\mathbb{V}}_i~=~{\mathbb{V}}~~.
 $$
Were this not so, the union would possess, by DEF 2, a nonzero complementary invariant subspace -- which would, by Lemma 1, be completely reducible, and therefore would contain an irreducible by Lemma 2.

Second, we have to construct a subset ${\cal{M}}\subset\cal I$ such that the sum over $\cal M$ is a *direct* sum:
$$
 \bigoplus_{i\in\cal M}{\mathbb{V}}_i~=~{\mathbb{V}}~~.
 $$
A subset ${\cal{J}}\subset\cal I$ is *direct* if the irreducibles ${\mathbb{V}}_i\,$, $i\in\cal J$, are in direct sum.

The set $\cal D$ of all direct subsets
[a] is not empty, because any singleton $\{i\}\in\cal I$ is a direct subset;
[b] is partially ordered by inclusion $\subseteq$;
[c] contains chains.

For each chain ${\cal{C}}\subset{\cal{D}}$,  the increasing union $\cal J_C$ $=\bigcup_{{\cal J}\in\cal C}\cal J$
[a] is an upper bound of the chain ${\cal{C}}\subset\cal D$,
[b] is itself a direct subset, i.e. belongs to $\cal D$.

Since any chain ${\cal{C}}\subset{\cal{D}}$ has an upper bound in $\cal D$, then the set $\cal D$ contains, by Zorn's lemma, a maximal element -- i.e. a maximal set ${\cal{M}}\subset\cal D$ such that $\{ {\mathbb V}_i\}$, $i\in\cal M$, are in direct sum.

For any $j\notin\cal M$, the intersection $\mathbb V_j~\cap $ $ \bigoplus_{i\in\cal M}{\mathbb V }_i $
is non-zero, because its vanishing would contradict the maximality of $\cal M~$.

(The vanishing of $\mathbb V_j~\cap $ $ \bigoplus_{i\in\cal M}{\mathbb V }_i $  would allow us to adjoin $j$ to $\cal M$ and to make  ${\cal{M}}\cup\{j\}$ the maximal element of the chain.)

Given the invariance of $\mathbb V_j$, this necessitates $ \mathbb V_j\subset \bigoplus_{i\in\cal M} \mathbb V_i$ for $\forall j\in\cal I$, wherefrom
$$
 \bigoplus_{i\in\cal M}{\mathbb{V}}_i~=~{\mathbb{V}}~~.
 $$
QED

---

AMENDMENT TO THE PROOF:

To show that $\cal J_{\cal C}$ is a direct subset, we need to show the linear independence of any family of vectors $ v_i:$ $v_i\in\mathbb V_i,$ $i\in\cal J_{\cal C}  $, which are zero for all but finitely many values of $i$.
Consider any finite family of nonzero vectors $\{v_i\}$ with indices $   i  =    j_1  ,~j_2  ,~.  .  .~,~j_n$ lying in ${\cal J_C}$. Each of these indices (say, $j_r$) belongs to a direct subset $   \cal J_r$ $\subset \cal C  $. By total ordering of $\cal C$, one of these direct subsets contains the others, so all the indices $   i  =   j_1  ,  j_2  ,~.  .  .~,  j_n$ reside in this direct subset. The corresponding spaces $\mathbb V_i$ are in direct sum, and non-zero vectors $v_i\in\mathbb V_i$ are linearly independent. Since this is true for any finite set $  j_1  ,~j_2  ,~.  .  .~,  j_n  \in  \cal J_{\cal C}  $, we conclude that $\cal J_C$ is a direct set, i.e. ${\cal{J_C}}\subset\cal D$.

Comment: Why should it be true that $\mathbb W$ equals $\mathbb U \oplus P(\mathbb U')$? \\ A union of subspaces is a subspace, but a union of closed subspaces is not a closed subspace.  (I also don't see why there should be any invariant subspaces of $\mathbb V$ not containing $v$.)

Comment: @LSpice  As ever, you are my saviour. So you believe that Lemma 1 is the culprit, right? (Out of sheer interest: does Lemma 2 stay in $L^2$ ?)

Comment: By the way, TeX note: $*$ `*` and $\star$ `\star` are different; you should not label an equation with one and switch to the other.  But even better is to use `\label`+`\eqref`, which will both enforce consistency and give you a nice clickable link.  Most importantly, I urge you not to include the huge amount of manual spacing you do.  TeX is very good at following best practices, and overriding it everywhere makes the post extremely unpleasant to read.

Comment: I'm not sure what "does Lemma 2 stay in $L^2$" [means](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428193/two-equivalent-definitions-of-semisimplicity-of-group-representations-proof-by#comment1101299_428193), but, as I [indicated](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428193/two-equivalent-definitions-of-semisimplicity-of-group-representations-proof-by#comment1101298_428193), I do not believe its proof, at least not as written.

Comment: @LSpice Also, would you like to present your observation not as a comment but as an Answer?  And, as ever, great many thanks for your time and help!

Comment: The two algebraic notions of completely reducible are equivalent.  The fact that complete reducibility passes to a subrepresentation is essentially the modular law which let's you verify that $U\oplus (U'\cap W)=W$ in your notation.

Comment: The problem with your argument in the L2 setting, it seems to me, is that you are only proving that closed invariant subspaces have complements and not all of them. In other words, you would need all invariant subspaces to have complements not just the topological ones.

Comment: You cannot prove there is an irreducible submodule if not all submodules have a complement,

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I think, I got it now. Many thanks!

Comment: The point is that if $V$ is completely reducible, every quotient is also a submodule because the kernel of the projection to the quotient has a complement.  So start with $V$, take a finitely generated submodule $W$  (this will likely not be closed and so you will have problems).  This will have an irreducible quotient $S$ by Zorn's lemma and then $S$ will be a submodule of $W$ and hence $V$.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg ...and by a submodule you imply a subrepresentation, correct? (Sorry, I am a physicist.)

Comment: @Michael_1812, yes.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Could you please help me formulate this conclusion in one sentence understandable to a layman? Can I say that  while the proof is correct and the two definitions are algebraically equivalent, we observe no such equivalence in this "counterexample", because in this example only closed subrepresentations are proven to be complemented? (Hmm, but in a Hilbert space *all* Hilbert subspaces are closed.)

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428193/two-equivalent-definitions-of-semisimplicity-of-group-representations-proof-by#comment1101303_428193), @BenjaminSteinberg's comments are much more to the point; I was just commenting as I read.

Comment: @LSpice To be honest, I am still a bit lost. Can I say that the theorem is correct algebraically, but not for closed subspaces? Can I still say that the discussed representation of $\mathbb R$ is completely reducible in the sense of of DEF 2 ?

Comment: To summarize @BenjaminSteinberg's comments: Definitions 1 and 2 are equivalent. Your action of $\mathbb R$ on $L^2(\mathbb R)$ is not a counterexample, because neither of the two definitions is satisfied. You showed in the question that Def. 1 fails in your example. Def. 2 also fails, because it requires invariant complements for **all** invariant subspaces, not just for the particular (closed) subspaces that you discussed in the question.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you indeed for this helpful summary!

Comment: Sorry I had to go offline. Yes not all subspaces are Hilbert because if they are not closed they need not be complete.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Could you please tell me regarding the proof of the Theorem: is it valid also for TVS spaces?Can we say that for TVS spaces the two definitions are equivalent?

Comment: What is a TVS space?

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Topological Vector Space

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg My question is formulated more accurately here
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4354611/topological-vector-spaces-in-direct-sum

Comment: I don’t think these things work well for topological vector spaces in general because things tend not to stay closed. I’m not an expert in topological vector spaces.

Comment: As in other comments: indeed, the sort of transfinite induction/Zorn's lemma argument in the proof that 2 implies 1 depends on the hypothesis being met that _all_ (stable) subspaces have complements. This hypothesis is not met in $L^2(\mathbb R)$ with the translation action of $\mathbb R$. The situation is "even worse" in Banach spaces, because, apart from representation theory, there are uncomplemented closed subspaces in some examples. There are few topological vector spaces where algebraic subspaces are closed: strict colimits of finite-dimensional I think is the only type.

Comment: @AndreasBlass On second thoughts, I would question your summary. You are saying that DEF 2 requires invariant complements for **all** invariant subspaces, not just for the closed ones. This may be a yawning gap in my education: can a Hilbert space at all possess open subspaces? More generally, can a Hilbert space have a subspace that is not Hilbert?             
[We physicists assume, on automatic pilot, that a subspace of a Hilbert space is Hilbert. Please correct me if I am erroneous in my superstition.]

Comment: @paulgarrett Dear Paul, many thanks for joining this discussion! Is my understanding correct that in my proof the maximal element (whose existence is ensured by Zorn) is not necessarily closed? This is what I suspected. But on the other hand, can I not say that the set $\cal D$ of all direct subsets contains closed spaces only, and therefore its maximal element must be closed?

Comment: @Michael_1812 An infinite-dimensional Hilbert space $H$ has many non-closed subspaces. (It does not have open subspaces other than $H$ itself, but I suspect you wrote "open" by mistake, while thinking "not closed".) For example, when $H$ is the space $\ell^2$ of square-summable sequences, the sequences that have only finitely many non-zero terms form a non-closed subspace.

Comment: Yes, @AndreasBlass, I had *non-closed* ones in mind. Thank you for correcting me. And thank you for answering my question. Also, when you said that DEF 1 = DEF 2, did you imply the equivalence in linear spaces only? Or also in Hilbert spaces? Or, more generally, in topological vector spaces?